# QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt4

Im  trying to send a signal from a non-main thread in PyQt but i dont know what am doing wrong! And when i execute the program it fails with this error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

here is my code:

```
 class Sender(QtCore.QThread):
        def __init__(self,q):
            super(Sender,self).__init__()
            self.q=q
        def run(self):

            while True:
                pass
                try: line = q.get_nowait()
             # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                except Empty: 
                    pass
                else: 
                   self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('tri()')) 
 class Workspace(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """ This class is for managing the whole GUI `Workspace'.
        Currently a Workspace is similar to a MainWindow
    """

    def __init__(self):  
try:
            from Queue import Queue, Empty
        except ImportError:
            while True:
    #from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x
                print "error"

        ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        p= Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/',stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize= 4024)
        q = Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q)) 
          t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        t.start()
        self.sender= Sender(q)
         self.connect(self.sender, QtCore.SIGNAL('tri()'), self.__action_About)
        self.sender.start()
```

I think that my way of send parameter to the thread is wrong...
I need to know how to send parameters to a thread, in my case i need to send `q` to the worker thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send parameters to a Qthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675140/how-to-send-parameters-to-a-qthread)

Comment: You've already asked this question, and you still haven't provided any code which actually uses QTextCursor.

Comment: It is likely that the asker was not actually directly using QTextCursor, but rather using GUI code from a thread that was not the GUI thread. Attempting this seems to result in this error arising from Qt-internal code, e.g. for QTextEdit.append(). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104779/qobject-qplaintextedit-multithreading-issues

Comment: @svk This truly is the correct answer, I think. I suggest you create an answer here. Flag me when you do that, such that I can vote for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Quite new to PyQt5, but this appears to happen when you try to do a GUI operation from a thread which is not the "application thread". I put this in quotes because it appears to be a mistake to think that, even in a fairly simple PyQt5 app, `QApplication.instance().thread()` will always return the same object.

The thing to do is to use the signal/slot mechanism to send any kind of data from a worker thread (a thread created in my case by extending `QtCore.QRunnable`, one other pattern apparently being `QtCore.QThread` and `QtCore.QObject.moveToThread`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782192/595305)).

Then also include a check in all your slot methods which are likely to receive data from a non-"application thread". Example which logs messages visually during execution:

```
def append_message(self, message):
    # this "instance" method is very useful!
    app_thread = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().thread()
    curr_thread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()
    if app_thread != curr_thread:
        raise Exception('attempt to call MainWindow.append_message from non-app thread')
    ms_now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
    self.messages_text_box.insertPlainText(f'{ms_now}: {message}\n')
    # scroll to bottom
    self.messages_text_box.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

It's all too easy to just call this inadvertently and directly from a non-"application thread".

Making such a mistake then raise an exception is good, because it gives you a stack trace showing the culprit call. Then change the call so that it instead sends a signal to the GUI class, the slot for which could be the method in the GUI class (here `append_message`), or alternatively one which then *in turn* calls `append_message`.

In my example I've included the "scroll to bottom" line above because it was only when I added that line that these "cannot queue" errors started happening. In other words, it is perfectly possible to get away with a certain amount of non-compliant handling (in this case adding some more text with each call) without any error being raised... and only later do you then run into difficulties. To prevent this, I suggest that EVERY method in a GUI class with GUI functionality should include such a check!

***Enforcement of thread compliance using a method decorator***

I now (2023) use this for most methods in my PyQt projects. Any failures show the **calling** stack (which in fact `logger.exception(...)` doesn't do in this context...)

```
# ideally, make your life easier and properly configure a non-root logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
...
def thread_check(gui_thread: bool):
    def pseudo_decorator(func):
        if not callable(func):
            # coding error: decorator has been applied to something which is not a function 
            raise Exception(f'func is non-callable type {type(func)}')
        def gui_checker_inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func.stack_trace = None
                if QtWidgets.QApplication == None:
                    return None
                if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() != None: 
                    app_thread = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().thread()
                    curr_thread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()
                    # None means we don't check the GUI status of the thread
                    if gui_thread != None:
                        if (curr_thread == app_thread) != gui_thread:
                            # NB WRONG THREAD! QT likely to crash soon afterwards if this happens ...
                            raise Exception(f'method {func.__qualname__} should have been called in {"GUI thread" if gui_thread else "non-GUI thread"}')
                def executing_func(*args, **kwargs):
                    func.stack_trace  = ''.join(traceback.format_stack())
                    thread_check.stack_trace  = ''.join(traceback.format_stack())
                    thread_check.func = func
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                return executing_func(*args, **kwargs)        
            except BaseException as e:
                msg = f'stack trace:\n{func.stack_trace}\n'
                if logger == None:
                    print(msg, file=sys.stderr)
                else:
                    logger.exception(msg)
                
                # NB a KeyboardInterrupt on the DOS screen from which the app was launched, will not be "seen"
                # until you put focus back on the app (from the DOS screen)... but when you do this will stop the app: 
                if isinstance(e, KeyboardInterrupt):
                    sys.exit()
                raise e
        return gui_checker_inner_function
    return pseudo_decorator
```

Usage:

```
@thread_check(True)
def my_gui_method(self):
    ...

@thread_check(False)
def my_non_gui_method(self):
    ...

@thread_check(None)
def can_work_in_either_context(self):
    ...
```

NB it is wrong to suppose there is little point in the last of these 3, where such compliance is not in fact checked. Qt failures are notorious for exceptions not being caught because nothing is in fact checking for an exception being raised! This will catch **all** `BaseException`s and log a nice calling stack trace. Otherwise you have to bracket the content of each method in `try ... except`. NB however, it won't actually catch all Qt exceptions thrown/raised in the C++ code but it often provides a lot of guidance to baffling crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().

Did you try to use `qRegisterMetaType` function?

The official manual [says](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmetatype.html):

> The class is used as a helper to marshall types in QVariant and in
>   queued signals and slots connections. It associates a type name to a
>   type so that it can be created and destructed dynamically at run-time.
>   Declare new types with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() to make them available to
>   QVariant and other template-based functions. **Call qRegisterMetaType()
>   to make type available to non-template based functions, such as the
>   queued signal and slot connections**.

Comment: The OP is using PyQt, which doesn't wrap `qRegisterMetaType`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the following notes to the @mike rodent's post which solved my problem (I'm using PyQt5):

1. Custom signals and slots can be used to avoid directly modifying GUI from thread other than "application thread" (I'm using Python threading module and the equivalent there to that is probably "main thread"). I find [this](https://programmer.help/blogs/some-understanding-of-custom-signal-in-pyqt5.html) website very useful for basic custom signal and slot setup. Pay attention to using a class (and not an instance) attribute.
2. To avoid the `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'` message I needed to find the following locations and add some code:

   - Before the function __init__ of the class MainWindow: definition of class attribute; I needed to use something like `class_attribute = pyqtSignal(str)`.
   - In the function __init__: `self.class_attribute.connect(self.slot_name)`
   - Inside of a thread (I mean the thread which is not the main thread): `self.class_attribute.emit(str)`
   - In the slot inside the main thread: "safety mechanism" proposed by @mike rodent.